# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't update when LocalStorage is changed (using store.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my view I want to display a list of items (subject names) which are saved in a LocalStorage element. My code in the view looks like this:

```
<div class="list">
  <a class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="subject in subjects">
    {{subject.name}}
  </a>
</div>
```

my controller looks like this:

```
.controller('SubjectCtrl', function ( $scope ) {

  $scope.subjects = store.get('subjects');

  $scope.submit = function() {
    if (store.get('subjects') != null) {
      var existing = store.get('subjects')
      var subject = [ { name: $scope.form.name, weighting: $scope.form.weighting, grades: [] } ]
      subject.add(existing)
      store.set('subjects', subject)
    }
    else {
      var subject = [ { name: $scope.form.name, weighting: $scope.form.weighting, grades: [] } ]
      store.set('subjects', subject)
    }
  };
})
```

The $scope.subjects variable gets the items from LocalStorage using Store.js (https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js, a Plugin that simplifies LocalStorage access) and provides them to the view.

The code underneath is triggered when the user submits a form to add a new subject. The form contains two inputs: name and weighting. When the form is submitted, the code checks if there are already any subjects inside the LocalStorage object 'subjects'. If yes, the new subject is added to the array of subjects and the LocalStorage is updated. If not, a LocalStorage object named 'subjects' is being created and the new subject is added.

The code above works as intended, **but my big problem is, that if a new subject is added to the array inside LocalStorage, Angular doesn't update the view** and I have to reload the page manually to see the new subject appearing in the list.

After some research, **I have learned that the problem may be caused because the LocalStorage object is updated outside of AngularJS' scope**. But I'm an Angular beginner and don't know what's the best way to notify Angular as soon as the object changes.

I appreciate any help!

**-- UPDATE --**

I have switched from store.js (which doesn't work well together with angular) to ngStorage (https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage). Maybe it's helping for somebody if I post my updated controller code using ngStorage:

```
.controller('SubjectCtrl', function ( $scope, $localStorage ) {
  $scope.$localStorage = $localStorage.$default({
    subjects: []
  });

  $scope.subjects = $localStorage.subjects;

  $scope.submit = function() {
    $localStorage.subjects.push({ name: $scope.form.name, weighting:  $scope.form.weighting, grades: [] });
  };
})
```

Comment: Does `$scope.$apply();` force an update in your case?

Comment: @Shomz not needed and won't help since `$scope.subjects` is not being updated. No need for `$apply` when scope is updated within an angular scoped function

Comment: @Giannizz biggest issue is you are thinking of the localStore first.....think the other way, so store mirrors the changes you make in scope, with exception of first load of controller when you need to retrieve local data. Slightly different when dealing with server updates...need to confirm server connection was made first

Comment: @charlietfl You're right, not sure why I assumed the changes are coming from an external source...

Comment: Thank you guys for answering and for providing me with solutions about how to solve this problem :) I've tried the solution artur proposed below, but it didn't have any effect even though it's the scope-first-localStorage-last-approach. Do you have any idea why his code doesn't work? I'm really confused right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a couple of things in your code that can be improved -- the most important: you never *inform* `$scope` about the change.
Try this one and let me know if it helped:

```
.controller('SubjectCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.subjects = store.get('subjects');
    if($scope.subjects == null) {
        $scope.subjects = [];
    }

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.subjects.push({ name: $scope.form.name, weighting: $scope.form.weighting, grades: [] });
        store.set('subjects', $scope.subjects)
    };
})
```

**-- UPDATE --**

The solution OP found is in the updated-question, above

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your code looks definitely tidier than mine ;) However, the problem still persists, I don't know what is wrong... I assume that the Idea of @charlietfl is also present in your answer (Save the stuff in LocalStorage secondary, after updating the view) and that's the way to go but I'm not sure why it doesn't work :/

Comment: @Giannizz what does not work? did you implement it? could you provide a plnkr?

Comment: @Giannizz I am pretty sure that the code is okay and will add elements properly. On Hinzufugen set `ng-click="submit();closeModal()"`.

Comment: @Giannizz I can look into the issue but provide a plnkr, please.

Comment: I tried to crease a plnkr but it couldn't load angular as soon as I pasted in my code. Let me know if you want a zip of my app or something.. I really appreciate your help mate!

Comment: @Giannizz for sure you should not use `ng-submit` if the there are more than one field on your form. (without a plnkr cannot help much more)

Comment: the issue was that I was thinking about localStorage in the first place (thanks @charlietfl for the idea) and make angular dependent on it. I now have found a way that lets me handle localStorage as an extension of angular: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage